# Why are my arrays showing up as 0 in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make a file that creates a array of 3 strings, than randomly displays one of the three 5 times. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php

$pk[0] = "PK Fire!<br/>";
$pk[1] = "PK Thunder!<br/>";
$pk[2] = "PK Freeze!<br/>";

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
Echo "" + $pk[rand(0,2)] + "";

?>
```

Comment: As an aside instead of rand() you can use array_rand(): `foreach(array_rand($pk, 5) as $key) echo $pk[$key];`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

. (dot) must be used instead of + to concatenate strings

```
Echo "" . $pk[rand(0,2)] . "";
```

instead of

```
Echo "" + $pk[rand(0,2)] + "";
```

Comment: When I've been in javascript for too long my php sometimes gets this problem too :)

Answer (score 8):

Jian Lin is correct, you're using "+" when you should be using "." to combine strings.

```
Echo "" + $pk[rand(0,2)] + "";
```

should become

```
echo "" . $pk[rand(0,2)] . "";
```

And really, you can just do:

```
echo $pk[rand(0,2)];
```

instead of concatenating blank strings before and after (which, as they're blank, add nothing).

Answer (score 5):

you need the "." to concatenate.

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain.

Comment: Bingo. The use of + to concatenate is essentially doing `echo 0+0+0;`.

Comment: you are combining the string to form a larger one... in PHP, it is a dot instead of "+".  If you remove the "" +  and  + "" part, it will work too.

Comment: an alternative is to use a comma: echo "", $pk[$something], "";

Answer (score 1):

By using the `+` operator, you're asking PHP to "coerce" all those variables into numeric values and add them up. Any thing that is not a number or a string that is a well-formed number will be converted to 0, and added together. Beware of this pitfall when comparing strings: use triple-equals rather than double-equals, lest you find that `"fish" == "0"`.